# jQuery trigger and bind to event on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

How can I both trigger and bind to an event after the page load?

The problem I am having is that in one place, on page-load I fire an event:

```
//producer.js
pageLoaded(){
   var e = jQuery.Event("eventA");
   $("body").trigger(e);
   ...}
```

and in another I bind to it:

```
//consumer.js
pageLoaded(){
   $("body").bind("eventA", function(args){console.log("Got it!");} );
   ... }
```

The problem is that the first time event is fired (when page is loaded) - the consumer does not see it. The second time event is fired, however, everything is fine!

I am guessing this is because event is actually fired BEFORE consumer starts listening to it.

Is there a good practice to follow when creating "triggers" and "listeners" to events - that have to work both on page load, and later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using something like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) will allow me to first load one javascript file, and then another.

So I can make `producer.js` dependent on `consumer.js`

Answer (score 1):

If there are no listeners when you triggered an event nothing will happen which is why you are not seeing anything on the first trigger.

Comment: I understand, but how can you get around this problem? I really need the event to be "caught" on page load. But I also need it to be triggered on page load. This is madness!!!

Comment: Then make sure that the consumer.js is loaded prior to producer.js

Comment: @drozzy - If my answer made any sense please accept it thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but I am still not sure how I would "make sure that consumer.js is loaded prior to producer.js"

Comment: How do you include these js on the page?

Comment: Well I include a lot of js files on the page. I don't want to artificially "order" the inclusion of them.

Comment: Just try to change the inclusion of these 2 js files in the required order. It will solve your problem.

Comment: Hm... what if someone in the future reorders them in the HTML page, and the thing stops working. This is very un-intuitive.

Comment: This is possible in every application. If you reorder the js inclusion it may not work as expected.

Comment: Yes, but only if the dependencies are static - i.e. i need some function from some library. However, mine are "runtime" dependencies - I can register to listen to events first, and then as providers get added, they will broadcast them to me. Perhaps you are right and I am making this way too complicated.

Comment: @drozzy - It will not the work that way, anyways if you are satisfied with my answer please mark it as an answer :)

Comment: Sorry but I didn't ask for the reason of why it doesn't work - but a workable solution. I want to see if any people have had a similar problem and came up with a more dynamic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to control the order of document.ready() calls .. perhaps the responses to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479713/jquery-multiple-document-ready-queue-order) or [this article](http://activelamp.com/blog/change-execution-order-documentready) might assist you