# JQuery - Binding / Appending to document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a ASP.NET MVC 3 application that is using JQuery. In this application, I have my _Layout.cshtml file and MyView.cshtml. In _Layout.cshtml I have something like the following:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="background-color:Gray; height:100%;">
  <div id="content" style="background-color:Silver;">
    @RenderBody()    
  </div>
  <div id="footer" style="background-color:Silver;">
    Footer
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    // Do stuff
    alert("Root Loaded");
  });
</script>
```

In MyView.cshtml, I have the following:

```
<div id="contentDiv">
  <!-- Page content is here -->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $().ready(function () {
      alert("Page Loaded");
    });
</script>
```

At this time, the "Page Loaded" message box appears before the "Root Loaded" message. I kind of understand why this is happening. However, I would like to write a method in MyView.cshtml that gets called after the root document.ready function is called. Am I making sense? Is there a way to do this? If so, how?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fire after all elements on the page are loaded, so, it should be later, than the ready event.

```
$(window).load(function () {
      alert("Whole page Loaded");
    });)
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider Queuing as suggested in the answer below:

[jQuery multiple document ready queue order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3479713/476786)